# How can we prevent adding special characters when we json_encode an array in php?

Tags: php, special-characters, jsonencoder

The main array is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'message' => string 'Dear subscriber, 
We are working to resolve your link down issue. 
It will take approximately 2-4 hours to fix the issue.We appreciate your cordial support and patience during this time.

Thanks for being with us.
Techno' (length=231)
      'created_at' => string '01:04 pm 11/01/2022' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'message' => string 'Dear subscriber, 
We are working to resolve your link down issue. 
It will take approximately 2-4 hours to fix the issue.We appreciate your cordial support and patience during this time.

Thanks for being with us.
Techno' (length=231)
      'created_at' => string '01:04 pm 11/01/2022' (length=19)
```

After json_encode, collection becomes like this (Where extra \n, \r are included which we do not want:

```
'[{"message":"Dear subscriber, \nWe are working to resolve your link down issue. \nIt will take approximately 2-4 hours to fix the issue.We appreciate your cordial support and patience during this time.\n\nThanks for being with us.\nTechno","created_at":"01:04 pm 11\/01\/2022"},{"message":"Dear subscriber, \nWe are working to resolve your link down issue. \nIt will take approximately 2-4 hours to fix the issue.We appreciate your cordial support and patience during this time.\n\nThanks for'... (length=1173)
```

Comment: write your messages on one line. \n are just json transcription of new lines.

Comment: Then what does \r mean?

Comment: Can we get rid of these special characters?

Comment: yes by removing new lines. New lines are characters, but you don't see them, they modify layout.  But if there are new lines, you'll get \n in json

Comment: In curl response, we get data like this including n. This does not make sense to us.

Comment: {"result":[{"message":"Dear subscriber, nWe are working to resolve your link down issue. nIt will take approximately 2-4 hours to fix the issue.

Comment: nWe, nIt     How can we detect new lines from here?

Comment: Why does it "not make sense" to you, that after a greeting formula like "Dear subscriber", there is a newline first ...? Or that multiple sentences are separated from each other with a line break in between them? That seems like a pretty normal thing to do. Reads & looks better, than if everything was just written in one long line. But if you insist on not wanting them, then loop over your data, and remove them via search&replace ...?

Answer (score 0):

If all what you need is to remove those two characters you mentioned (new lines basically) you can try something like this on json_encode $result:

```
$result = str_replace("\\n", '', $result);

$result = str_replace("\\r", '', $result);
```

More options you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991198/remove-newline-character-from-a-string-using-php-regex) for example.